# How do I filter out rows based on another data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

So I need to filter out rows from one data frame using another dataframe as a condition for it.

df1:

```
system     code
AIII-01    423
CIII-04    123
LV-02      142
```

df2:

```
StatusMessage    Event
123              Gearbox warm up
```

So for this example I need to remove the rows that has the code 423 and 142.

How do I do that?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,left_on='code',right_on='StatusMessage')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug and play script for you. If this doesn't work on your regular code, check to make sure you have the same types in the same columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"system": ["AIII", "CIII", "LV"], "Code": [423, 123, 142]}
)

df2  = pd.DataFrame(
    {"StatusMessage": [123], "Event": ["Gearbox warm up"]}
)

### This is what you need
df1 = df1[df1.Code.isin(df2.StatusMessage.unique())]

print(df1)
```

Comment: Anurag's code will also work (and should be used if you want merging). You could also drop the `.unique()` in my code, depending on spacetime requirements.

Comment: See my edit! Should help. If not, message me back.